# Apache vhost: Alias and RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, unix, alias, virtualhost

I have one URL (domain), for multiple directories (project). And I have a very odd behaviour when putting a .htaccess in it.

- `sub.mywebsite.com/` => `/foo/bar/things`
- `sub/mywesite.com/pro` => `/srv/www/new`

VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /foo/bar/things
    ServerName sub.mywebsite.com
    Alias /pro /srv/www/new
</VirtualHost>
```

And it works perfectly. When I go on `sub.mywebsite.com/` it hit the `/foo/bar/things` dir and the other way around.

---

Now, let's add a simple `.htaccess` in `/srv/www/new` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$    php/file.php?text=$1   [L,QSA]
```

So when I go on `sub.mywebsite.com/pro/hello/` the file called is supposed to be `/srv/www/new/php/file.php` with a GET arg. I double-checked, the rule is good.

Here is the end of the RewriteLogLevel 4:

```
192.168.123.123 - - [25/Apr/2018:19:28:11 +0200] [sub.mywebsite.com/sid#7f317dd08b8][rid#7f37eca9f78/initial] (1) 
[perdir /srv/www/new/] internal redirect with /srv/www/new/php/file.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

And an [online htaccess checker](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) confirm it: `The new url is http://sub.mywebsite.com/php/file.php%3Ftext=testing`

But I've got an apache 404 not found:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /srv/www/new/php/file.php was not found on this server.
```

And yes, `ls -l /srv/www/new/php/file.php` the file exists.

The VERY ODD part is this: in the apache error log, I've got:

```
[Wed Apr 25 19:45:30 2018] [error] [client 192.168.123.123] File does not exist: /foo/bar/things/srv
```

---

**Questions**:

1. What the hell is that? Why the file in the error_log is not the same
   as the one displayed on my browser?
2. Why apache can't load the right file `/srv/www/new/php/file.php` as the .htaccess ask it?

Feel free to ask me more data if needed. I want to understand!

NB: there is no .htaccess in `/foo/bar/things` ; I've tried a lot of things in my vhost, like adding a `<directory>`, etc.

Comment: You most probably need to add `RewriteBase "/pro"` to your .htaccess

Comment: @DusanBajic damn you're actually right.. Could you please elaborate it in an answer and maybe try to explain both questions, so I can accept your contribution? Many thanks!

Comment: I probably don't have enough knowledge about httpd internals to give proper explanation, but I will try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to both of your questions is already shown on your screen and in your logs:

```
The requested URL /srv/www/new/php/file.php was not found on this server.
```

The requested **URL**.

```
AH00128: File does not exist: /foo/bar/things/srv/www/new/php/file.php
```

**File** does not exist.

So, apache is not trying to fetch the file `file.php` which is located in `/srv/www/new/php/` folder on your filesystem. It is trying to open URL `http://sub.mywebsite.com/srv/www/new/php/file.php`, which explains both the browser error and the line in your error log, since for that URL it really should look into `/foo/bar/things/srv/www/new/php/file.php`.

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html:

> The rewrite engine may be used in .htaccess files and in 
>   sections, with some additional complexity.
>  (...)
>  See the
>   [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) directive for more information regarding what prefix
>   will be added back to relative substitutions.
>  (...)
>  The
>   RewriteBase directive specifies the URL prefix to be used for
>   per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule directives that substitute a
>   relative path. This directive is **required** when you use a relative
>   path in a substitution in per-directory (htaccess) context.
>  (...)
>   This misconfiguration would normally cause the server to look for an
>   directory under the document root.

Solution: add `RewriteBase "/pro"` to your .htaccess

You can see the difference in Rewrite Log:

Without RewriteBase:

```
[perdir /srv/www/new/] rewrite 'hello/' -> 'php/file.php?text=hello'
[perdir /srv/www/new/] add per-dir prefix: php/file.php -> /srv/www/new/php/file.php
[perdir /srv/www/new/] internal redirect with /srv/www/new/php/file.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

With `RewriteBase "/pro"`:

```
[perdir /srv/www/new/] rewrite 'hello/' -> 'php/file.php?text=hello'
[perdir /srv/www/new/] add per-dir prefix: php/file.php -> /srv/www/new/php/file.php
[perdir /srv/www/new/] trying to replace prefix /srv/www/new/ with /pro
strip matching prefix: /srv/www/new/php/file.php -> php/file.php
add subst prefix: php/file.php -> /pro/php/file.php
[perdir /srv/www/new/] internal redirect with /pro/php/file.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Answer (score 1):

*Update for Apache > 2.4.16*

Since version 2.4.16 `RewriteBase` directive is not required when the request is mapped via `Alias`:

> This directive is *required* when you use a relative path in a substitution in per-directory (htaccess) context unless any of the following conditions are true:

> - The original request, and the substitution, are underneath the `[DocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot)` (as opposed to reachable by other means, such as `[Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)`).
> - The *filesystem* path to the directory containing the `[RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)`, suffixed by the relative substitution is also valid as a URL path on the server (this is rare).
> - In Apache HTTP Server 2.4.16 and later, this directive may be omitted when the request is mapped via `[Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias)` or `[mod_userdir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_userdir.html)`.

So basically you don't get any `AH00128: File does not exist:` errors anymore.

Worth noting that CentOS 7.x comes with Apache 2.4.6 with security patches:  as for 2022/01/07 you get 2.4.6-97.2 that fixes CVE-2021-40438. So if you want to manage multiple alias you need to upgrade with a different package, but this is another story...

Comment: Thanks for this update! Indeed, that should clear all the AH00128.